# 1994 Giant Iguana front sprocket

Tags: crankset, compatibility, sprocket

I have a 1994 Giant Iguana.  The teeth on the front sprocket are significantly worn and the middle sprocket is cracked.  Are there replacement sprockets for this bike?

Comment: From the images I can find online it appears to be steel chainrings (3 of them), but on a  5-bolt spider that may well accept some aluminum rings.

Comment: @DanielRHicks. At least for the 2 bigger rings. For longevity reasons the smaller ring was usually steel in the days.

Answer (score 2):

Without more info about the specifics of your crank set it's hard to answer exactly what size you need, but yes, they can be replaced. You will want to know the bolt pattern and bolt circle diameter. What brand is the crank set? Shimano? Maybe add a picture. Depending on the condition of the chain and cassette, it may be wise to consider replacing those too.

Comment: If the chainrings are riveted to the crank, which was quite common, you'll have to replace the crankset as well.

Comment: That's unlikely.